# DISTINCT method using Laravel 5 eloquent query builder

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm struggling to get unique results when using the **DISTINCT** method in laravel. This is my query

```
//Get users that are part of this sector

        $users = DB::table('users')->distinct()
                            ->join('projects', 'users.id', '=', 'projects.userID')
                            ->where('projects.sectorID', '=', $sector->sectorID)
                            ->get();
        dd($users);
```

The result shows 3 users with the same ID, when I only want one of them in the results.

How should I change my query?

Comment: did you mean the user id and the project sector id are all same in the three result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use group by id

```
$users = DB::table('users')
     ->join('projects', 'users.id', '=', 'projects.userID')
     ->where('projects.sectorID', '=', $sector->sectorID)
     ->groupBy('users.id')
     ->get();

dd($users);
```

Comment: Perfect, do I still need the distinct with groupby? or can I take that out?

Comment: Group by does quite the same as distinct so no need for distinct